# How to set default Style at current position in CKEditor..?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How to set the some default CKEditor styles(Presented in Styles combo box) at the current position through javascript.?

For example if the cursor in one position, i have to set the 'Marker: Yellow' style for that position after typing any character it should change to Yellow. Is it Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you, but isn't you just want to exec command applying (or removing) e.g. bold style? If yes you can do this by:

```
editor.execCommand('bold');
```

If you've got empty selection (caret) placed somewhere in the text, before executing this command, editor will create empty `<strong>^</strong>` element, so when user starts to type, the text will be bolded.

**Update**

Styles are applied in a little bit different way.

```
var style = new CKEDITOR.style(
    { name: 'Blue Title', element: 'h3', styles: { 'color': 'Blue' } });
style.apply(editor.document);
```

That will apply Blue Title style to the current selection. You can find other styles definitions in `_source/plugins/styles/styles/default.js` (http://dev.ckeditor.com/browser/CKEditor/trunk/_source/plugins/styles/styles/default.js) or you can get them in the code:

```
editor.getStylesSet(function(stylesDefinitions) {
    // stylesDefinitions is an array
});
```

Comment: Thanks. yeah it works fine. I want that Styles combo box styles to be applied. For example 'Marker: Yellow','Marker: Green' like this. Is it possible..?

Comment: Thanks..Its working only which has an 'styles:{...}'. It's not working for the styles 'Typewriter,Computer Code,Deleted Text'. How to set these styles..